# Why do .capitalize method downcase other words in string?

Tags: ruby, regex

So I was wondering why the 'capitalize' method actively lower cases the first letter of other strings in the sentence.

```
#This makes sense
"mike smith".capitalize
"Mike smith"

#This also makes sense
"Mike smith".capitalize
"Mike smith"

#This confuses me
"mike Smith".capitalize
"Mike smith"

#Also confuses me
"jim the BIG BOY".capitalize
"Jim the big boy"
```

I assumed that the capitalize method would look for the char at index '0' and upcase it.

P.S. I would love an answer that explains not just why (how method works), but "why". To "capitalize" something doesn't imply to make sure everything else is lower case in spoken English unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: The "why" is because the method name is a mistake/bug/error/surprise.  :)  It's documented clearly, and is the same as python's capitalize, yet everyone I know expects it to do something slightly different, such as upcase the first letter (and not touch the rest), or do word-capitals, or do smart capitals akin to perl's Text::Capitalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is surprising behavior, and it'd be reasonable to make the assumption you made.

The rationale is presumably that `capitalize` puts the string into "capitalized state", where a string is capitalized if and only if it matches `/^[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. The answer by S M Al Mamun is correct.

Comment: The question wasn't asking what the method does, it was asking why it does that.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby documentation for [String#capitalize](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) states it will only capitalize the first character:

> Returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase
>   and the remainder to lowercase.